# Share the same settings between multiple gnuplots settings

Tags: gnuplot

I've got multiple gnuplot files to generate the same graph but over different time ranges. So I have one which does render all, one which does render only the last 48 hours and one does render a specific month.

My question is now, is there a way to reuse most of the settings (as they are mostly identical) and only change the value for the plot range and the output file?

These are for example the 48 h settings:

```
set xlabel "Date (UTC)"
set ylabel "Size (Gibibytes)"
set title sprintf("Storagespace used and available (Generated: %s)", date)
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
set format x "%Y\n%m-%d\n%H:%M"
set xtics rotate
set terminal svg size 1280,720
set output "/var/www/sizes/sizes-graph-48h.svg" 
set datafile separator "    "
set autoscale xfix
set key below
set grid xtics ytics
FACTOR=1024*1024
plot "< tail -48 /home/fabian/sizes" using 1:($3/FACTOR) title 'Used by 4th/Aufnahme' with lines lc rgb "#008080", \
     "" using 1:($2/FACTOR) title 'Used by 3rd/Aufnahme' with lines lc rgb "#65000B", \
     "" using 1:($5/FACTOR) title 'Available on 4th' with lines lc rgb "blue", \
     "" using 1:($4/FACTOR) title 'Available on 3rd' with lines lc rgb "red", \
     "" using 1:(($5+$3*17/20)/FACTOR) title 'Est. max. available on 4th' with lines lc rgb "#0F52BA", \
     "" using 1:(($4+$2*17/20)/FACTOR) title 'Est. max. available on 3th' with lines lc rgb "#E62020", \
     20 notitle
```

And here is the diff between the 48 h settings and the settings for a specific month:

```
9c9
< set output "/var/www/sizes/sizes-graph-48h.svg" 
---
> set output sprintf("/var/www/sizes/sizes-graph-%s.svg", month)
15c15
< plot "< tail -48 /home/fabian/sizes" using 1:($3/FACTOR) title 'Used by 4th/Aufnahme' with lines lc rgb "#008080", \
---
> plot sprintf("< grep \"%s*\" /home/fabian/sizes", month) using 1:($3/FACTOR) title 'Used by 4th/Aufnahme' with lines lc rgb "#008080", \
```

As you can see, they are identical except for the output file (okay it would be possible to set `month` to `48h`) and the plot range parameter. To be complete here are difference of the 48 h settings to the “overall” settings:

```
9c9
< set output "/var/www/sizes/sizes-graph-48h.svg" 
---
> set output "/var/www/sizes/sizes-graph.svg" 
15c15
< plot "< tail -48 /home/fabian/sizes" using 1:($3/FACTOR) title 'Used by 4th/Aufnahme' with lines lc rgb "#008080", \
---
> plot "/home/fabian/sizes" using 1:($3/FACTOR) title 'Used by 4th/Aufnahme' with lines lc rgb "#008080", \
```

Okay here has the output file no dash at the end, but I could use something like `set output sprintf("/var/www/sizes/sizes-graph%s.svg", range)` where `range` is like `month` before but with a leading dash.

But the main problem is: Once I use tail, in the other case I use grep and in the last case I use neither (although I could use grep which matches all lines). So is there a way to say something like `gnuplot settings.gnuplot plotsource="< tail -48 /home/fabian/sizes"`?

Fabian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can reduce the script call to have only a single parameter to pass to the script. This hides even more details inside this one gnuplot script:

```
set xlabel "Date (UTC)"
set ylabel "Size (Gibibytes)"
set title sprintf("Storagespace used and available (Generated: %s)", \
    "`date -u +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S (%Z)"`")
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
set format x "%Y\n%m-%d\n%H:%M"
set xtics rotate
set terminal svg size 1280,720
if (exists('month')) {
    source = sprintf('< grep "%s*" /home/fabian/sizes', month)
    name = month
} else {
    if (!exists('hours')) { hours = 48 }
    name = sprintf('%dh', hours)
    source = sprintf('< tail -%d /home/fabian/sizes', hours)
}
set output sprintf("/var/www/sizes/sizes-graph-%s.svg", name)
set datafile separator "    "
set autoscale xfix
set key below
set grid xtics ytics
FACTOR=1024*1024
plot source using 1:($3/FACTOR) title 'Used by 4th/Aufnahme' with lines lc rgb "#008080", \
     "" using 1:($2/FACTOR) title 'Used by 3rd/Aufnahme' with lines lc rgb "#65000B", \
     "" using 1:($5/FACTOR) title 'Available on 4th' with lines lc rgb "blue", \
     "" using 1:($4/FACTOR) title 'Available on 3rd' with lines lc rgb "red", \
     "" using 1:(($5+$3*17/20)/FACTOR) title 'Est. max. available on 4th' with lines lc rgb "#0F52BA", \
     "" using 1:(($4+$2*17/20)/FACTOR) title 'Est. max. available on 3th' with lines lc rgb "#E62020", \
     20 notitle
```

Now you can call the script either with

```
gnuplot -e "month='sep'" /home/fabian/sizetable-base.gnuplot
```

or

```
gnuplot -e "hours=48" /home/fabian/sizetable-base.gnuplot
```

which would also be the default if called without setting `hours` or `month`.

Comment: Ah! I didn't know that you can add such logic to the file. After I updated my gnuplot (the Ubuntu installation was still using 4.4) I got it to work (although I had to make some adjustments, like generating a graph with all data, when neither parameter is specified). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

depending on how similar the things are, you can use gnuplot's `call` command.  Otherwise, you can break up the separate components into files and `load` the components you need.  (`call` is like `load` except that it accepts additional arguments.)

Comment: As I already using a bash script to set the parameters I could add another parameter (with `-e`) for the source of the plot instead of using `call`. And `load` can't replace everything, as it wouldn't substitute the `plot` command which is quite large. About the similarity: They are very similar as you can see in the diffs: Of 21 lines 2 needed to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Okay one solution I found is using bash. There is already the `date` parameter for the title, which I automatically generate using bash. So I created a basic gnuplot template:

```
set xlabel "Date (UTC)"
set ylabel "Size (Gibibytes)"
set title sprintf("Storagespace used and available (Generated: %s)", date)
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
set format x "%Y\n%m-%d\n%H:%M"
set xtics rotate
set terminal svg size 1280,720
set output sprintf("/var/www/sizes/sizes-graph-%s.svg", type)
set datafile separator "    "
set autoscale xfix
set key below
set grid xtics ytics
FACTOR=1024*1024
plot source using 1:($3/FACTOR) title 'Used by 4th/Aufnahme' with lines lc rgb "#008080", \
     "" using 1:($2/FACTOR) title 'Used by 3rd/Aufnahme' with lines lc rgb "#65000B", \
     "" using 1:($5/FACTOR) title 'Available on 4th' with lines lc rgb "blue", \
     "" using 1:($4/FACTOR) title 'Available on 3rd' with lines lc rgb "red", \
     "" using 1:(($5+$3*17/20)/FACTOR) title 'Est. max. available on 4th' with lines lc rgb "#0F52BA", \
     "" using 1:(($4+$2*17/20)/FACTOR) title 'Est. max. available on 3th' with lines lc rgb "#E62020", \
     20 notitle
```

This needs 3 parameters: `date`, `type` and `source`. The bash script to use the last 48 entries (= hours) then looks like:

```
gnuplot -e "date='`date -u +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S (%Z)"`'" -e "type='48h'" -e "source='< tail -48 /home/fabian/sizes'" /home/fabian/sizetable-base.gnuplot
```